# MS-Access date comparison Datatype conflict

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

In my Project I have Orders which contain an amount of Hours which have to be invoiced by a Rate, both of them are stored in tables. The Orders have a ValidFrom date. All Orders have to be invoiced by the last Rate where the ValidFrom is before the Order.TimeStamp.

The solution that I've tried is:

```
OrderDate = DLookup("TimeStamp", "Order", "OrderID=" & ThisOrderID & ")
LastRateDate = DMAX ("ValidFrom", "CompanyRate", "CompanyID=" & ThisCompanyID & " AND ValidFrom <=" & OrderDate)
CompanyRate = DLookup ("Rate","CompanyRate", "CompanyID=" & ThisCompanyID & " AND "ValidFrom =" & LastRateDate)
```

This gives several different errors:

- without semicolons (as written): Syntax error missing Operator.
- with single semicolon ' Datatype Conflict
- with double semicolon " (chr(34)) Datatype Conflict

I use a german Computer, with german as Windows and MS-Access language. I run the MS-Access 2013

How should I solve this?

Comment: Why don't you create a query and JOIN your tables ? DLookup and similar functions are highly inefficient

Comment: This how I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the proper syntax:

```vb
OrderDate = DLookup("TimeStamp", "Order", "OrderID = " & ThisOrderID & "")
LastRateDate = DMax("ValidFrom", "CompanyRate", "CompanyID = " & ThisCompanyID & " AND ValidFrom <= #" & Format(OrderDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
CompanyRate = DLookup("Rate", "CompanyRate", "CompanyID = " & ThisCompanyID & " AND ValidFrom = #" & Format(LastRateDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```